# Swift: determine what object called a function?

Tags: swift

I am writing some Swift code and I would like to know the class of the object that called the function. I don't want to pass in any parameters. From within the function I want to be able to know who called it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean you want to know the specific class instance that called a method, or what context a global function was called from?

Comment: I'd like to know the class of the object that called the method.

Comment: Do you just want to print it to the console, or do you want to actively engage with it?

Comment: Also: You're talking about a method just getting the name of it's own class, right?

Comment: I want to engage it actively so what I am looking for is a lightweight way of retrieving the CLASS of the object that called a function. Whether the function is in the same object or another object I want it to work either way...

Comment: do u got any clue abt what object called function? @zumzum

Answer (score 48):

If you want to do that using Swift, you can do this:

```swift
func debug(file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) -> String {
    return "\(file):\(line) : \(function)"
}
```

Comment: very nice. Thank you

Comment: There is no way to call that form obj-c, right? I'd like to make a Logger Class and also the obj-c files in my project would need to use it...

Comment: You can call it from Objective-C code. I have a logger that I use in 2 projects (Swift and Objective-C) https://github.com/elo7/nayau

Comment: This does not answer the question. Poster asked to find caller of the method without passing it in via parameter. This simply prints the method / name of class currently in file same as __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ in ObjC

Comment: @Vlad is correct. My bad on marking it as answered. Thanks

Comment: That's clever how it gets the default value

Answer (score 24):

To access the underlying class of a method from within itself, use the `dynamicType` property:

```
 self.dynamicType
```

If you want to know the origin of the original call, you can use `NSThread` to return debugging information about the stack:

```
 NSThread.callStackSymbols()
```

This method returns a descriptive array of values that you're used to seeing when exceptions are thrown. The strings represent a backtrace of all current activity on your call stack.

I don't want to be presumptuous, but it seems to me that outside of debugging, there isn't a good reason, conceptually, at least, to know the origin of a specific method call for any and every function. If you need to retrieve the class Type of the last method call on the stack, why not implement an interface that lets you access this information through a straightforward route?

Comment: I encountered the same need while implementing an observer pattern, where I had to inform all the listeners but not the caller of a property change.

Comment: `NSThread.callStackSymbols()` was exactly what i was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I need that to find a quite wired bug because I called a viewController explicit and (wrongly) implicit ... very hard to find, and that gave me all the information I needed Thanks!

Comment: Newer Swift versions: `Thread.callStackSymbols`

Answer (score 17):

You can use following template to know from which file, line number in file, and function this someFunction is called:

```
func someFunction(file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function)
{
    NSLog("\(file.lastPathComponent):\(line) : \(function)")
}
```

Comment: So this is nice, but is there a way to get the class of the caller? No the class in terms of "String".

Comment: If you do ` NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file).deletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent `, it will likely give you the class if your class is in its own file.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift:**

Add a `(sender: Anyobject)` as parameter to that function, and then print the sender (the function caller) like this:

```
func yourFunc(sender: AnyObject){
     print(sender)
}
```

Or add a symbolic breakpoint with a `po thread` to see the stack trace of the caller of the method

Comment: Passing `#line` and `#function` directly to `print` is incorrect in this case since it will just print the line number of that print statement, and the function holding the print statement. Instead, we are interested in the caller of that function and the line where that function was called, so `#line` and `#function` should be default arguments to that function (like shown by other answers)

Comment: @agirault thanks for your comments, i have edited the post, and added other way to see the caller.

Answer (score 1):

**FormatPrint.swift**, newest way - struct log, hope it help someone!

```swift
import Foundation
import OSLog

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
fileprivate let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "Global")

@inline(__always)
func formatPrint(_ text: String, level: OSLogType = .info, file: String = #fileID, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
#if DEBUG
    let currentDate = Date()
    let info = """
                >>  1  \(currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970) - [\(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: currentDate, dateStyle: .long, timeStyle: .full))]
                >>  2  \(file)
                >>  3  \(function):\(line)
                >>  4  \(text)
                
                """
    
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        logger.log(level: level, "\(info)")
    } else {
        print("=====  \(level)")
        print(info)
    }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining together a couple of answers and comments:

```
func function(file: String = #file) {
    if let url = URL(string: file) {
        let className = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
        print(className)
    }
}
```