# Define custom NSAssert that includes line, class and general formatting

Tags: ios, xcode

As the title reads, how could I define a custom `NSAssert` which would include the line, class, and formatting as per my `NSLog` below:

`#define NSLog(__FORMAT__, ...) NSLog((@"%@: " __FORMAT__), NSStringFromClass([self class]), ##__VA_ARGS__)`

The problem is that `NSAssert` has a BOOL value first before the rest of the arguments are taken under account. I can't seem to find a solution without taking out the arguments and separating them.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Long story short, I'm looking for something like this:

`#define DebugAssert(__VA_ARGS__[0], @"%@: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), __VA_ARGS__[1])`

Comment: does it have to be objc? :)

Comment: No, not really :) @sloik

Comment: So you can define a function: `func CoolAssert(stuff: Any..., file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    print("\(file): \(line): \(stuff)")
}' and you call it `CoolAssert(stuff: "123", 123)` or check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954361/swift-determine-what-object-called-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSAssert` macro is defined like this:

```
#define NSAssert(condition, desc, ...)  /* the implementation */
```

So, the condition is already a separate parameter from the format string and the variable argument list. There should be no problem doing something similar to what you did for `NSLog`:

```
#define MyAssert(condition, desc, ...) \
    NSAssert(condition, (@"%@: " desc), NSStringFromClass([self class]), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```