# Can I know if a function is a method? If so, can I know its object?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

In Swift, a method is a special type of function, one attached to an object.

If I am given an arbitrary function, I want to know if it is a method. If it is, I want to know the object it is attached to.

Something like this:

```
func ownerOfFunction(_ f: () -> Void) -> Any? {
  return isMethod(f) ? getObject(f) : nil
}
```

Does anything like `isMethod()` or `getObject()` exist?

Comment: Could you explain what your goal is for doing this? It’s an interesting question. The reason for using a generic function is because the specific type is not important. So trying to find information about the specific type would seem like a code smell as it’s breaking the reason to use a non-specific function in the first place. Still... it’s an interesting question. 

Comment: Thanks! If I can do this, I _think_ I can use pithier, _better_ autoclosured `fn(self.method)` instead of `fn(self, selector: #selector(method)`. For an extension on `NotificationCenter`. Also, it's interesting. ;)

Comment: Question asked here is close to what you're asking, except for determining if it's a method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954361/swift-determine-what-object-called-a-function.  Some of the answers might be helpful.

Comment: @Wattholm That question is asking about what _called_ a function (parsing the call stack is probably the answer). I'm instead asking what object, if any, _owns_ a function (thereby making it a method).

Answer (score 0):

```
func ownerOfFunc<T> (_ parameter: AnyObject,_ type: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return parameter is T
}
protocol P1 {}
protocol P2: P1 {}
class C1: NSObject, P2 {
    @objc func fuc1() {}
    func fuc2() {}
}
let o = C1()

o.responds(to: Selector("fuc1")) // true (Works only Objc selectors)
o.responds(to: Selector("fuc2")) // false

ownerOfFunc(o, P1.self) // true
ownerOfFunc(o, P2.self) // true
ownerOfFunc(o, Int.self) // false
```

Comment: Interesting, maybe, but definitely not what I'm asking.