# How to get a method’s defining class’s name?

Tags: swift, static-methods

I’m using the following to log some function calls.

```
func functionWasCalled(file: String = #file, function: String = #function) {
    print("Function \(function) of file \(file) was called.")
}
```

When its caller is a method, I’d like `functionWasCalled` to also print the **name of the class** to which the caller belongs. Even when that method is static. And I don’t want to pass any explicit argument to functionWasCalled. What can I do?

Comment: do you want to print defining class name or the caller class name?

Comment: I believe there is some confusion and people are reading this as printing the name of the class that `functionWasCalled` belongs to. You may want to make this a bit more clear that you mean the *caller's* type. (It seems clear to me; but is obviously confusing a lot of people.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: determine what object called a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954361/swift-determine-what-object-called-a-function)

Comment: I'm pretty certain there is no solution to this problem in the way that you want. You can read Thread.callStackSymbols, but it's unlikely to be useful in a desymbolicated (release) build, even if you implement the demangling. In ObjC this is achieved with preprocessor macros, but they don't exist in Swift, and there's no way to evaluate a default value at the call site except for the specific #-literals provided.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks. Hope it’s better now. Do tell me if it’s not.

Comment: @Johnykutty I think not. The first answer requires adding an explicit parameter to the call, which would be cumbersome. The second and third seem similar to what I’m doing, with no reference to the caller’s defining class. The fourth uses the caller’s self, which is not available in my case, and callStackSymbols, from which I don’t see a clean way to extract what I need.

Comment: I did try to add “self” to the default arguments of functionWasCalled, but this doesn’t compile:
func functionWasCalled(file: String = #file, function: String = #function, self: Any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe what you're specifically asking for is possible. There's no way I know of to evaluate something in your caller's context implicitly, except the provided #-literals.

That said, if you will change your syntax slightly, you can get the effect you want.

```
public class Logger {
    public let caller: String

    public init(for caller: Any) {
        self.caller = "\(type(of: caller))"
    }

    public func info(_ message: String, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) {
        print("Function \(function) of \(caller) in file \(file) was called.")
    }
}
```

Now, in objects that use the logger, they just need to create their own with a consistent name like `log`. Make sure your Logger is stateless, so it's ok that they get created on demand.

```
class MyLoggingThing {
    var log: Logger { Logger(for: self) }

    func doSomething() {
        log.info("Let's do this")
    }
}

// Function doSomething() of MyLoggingThing in file MyPlayground.playground was called.
```

You can make this a little nicer with an extension, and handle static methods:

```
protocol Logging {}
extension Logging {
    static var log: Logger { Logger(for: self) }
    var log: Logger { Logger(for: self) }
}

class MyLoggingThing: Logging {
    static func doSomethingStatic() {
        log.info("Even static")
    }
    func doSomething() {
        log.info("Let's do this")
    }
}
```

Note that static methods will show the type as `MyLoggingThing.Type`. That's good or bad, depending on what you want. If you don't like the extra `.Type`, you can add an extra `Logger.init` like this:

```
public init(for staticCaller: Any.Type) {
    self.caller = "\(staticCaller)"
}
```

That will cause types to be evaluated as themselves rather than as their metatypes.

If your logger is stateful or has a central configuration, or other situation where lots of loggers might be a problem, you should split apart the stateful "engine" part from this front-end. You can also make `log` a lazy var or otherwise initialize it in `init` when `self` is available.

In my personal Logging module, I also have a global "root" Logger called `Log` (with a leading capital). That makes it easier for functions that might not want to name themselves (such as top level functions or closures).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String(describing: self)
```

Like here:

```
class Foo {
    func test () {
        print(String(describing: self))
    }
}

let f = Foo()

f.test()
```

Output:

```
Foo
```

Comment: Can you show how to use this with the function I have provided?

Comment: Using `self` here is most likely incorrect since this function is probably defined in a logging class or some other common class.

Answer (score 0):

For a class name, you can use `self.classForCoder` and for the filename, you can also use `#fileID`

```
    func functionWasCalled(file: String = #file, function: String = #function, fileID: String = #fileID, callClass: AnyObject?) {
        print("Function \(function) of file \(file) was called.")
        print("File id", fileID)
        print("Class is - ", callClass?.classForCoder ?? self.classForCoder)
    }
```

Comment: What would callClass be?

Comment: it's the class from which this function is called. ex. self.functionWasCalled(callClass: self)

Comment: I don’t want to have to explicitly pass any argument. I should have made this clearer, sorry. I’ve edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: did you try ```self.dynamicType``` ?

Comment: I don’t have access to the caller’s self.